# Flutter web - Getting cookie from the request

Tags: flutter, http

I've a web app in flutter 3.13.8 with two pages that corresponds to a two widget Uno and Due.

The second one respond to an http request

```
http://localhost:8080/#/Due
```

How can i inside the Due widget get the cookie that is send with the request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pub: https://pub.dev/packages/sweet_cookie

If you don't like using a pub, you can do it directly using the html 'window' property (available in `universal_html`).

To get a cookie:

```dart
final String? value = window.localStorage[key];
```

To set a cookie:

```dart
window.localStorage[key] = value;
```

To delete a cookie:

```dart
window.localStorage.remove(key);
```

To clear all cookies:

```dart
window.localStorage.clear();
```

Or even better, with no pubs (if you know your application is only html):

```dart
import 'dart:html';

final cookie = document.cookie ?? '';
final entries = cookie.split('; ').map((item) {
  final split = item.split('=');
  return MapEntry(split[0], split[1]);
});
final cookieMap = Map.fromEntries(entries);
```

To set cookies back into browser:

```dart
document.cookie="key=value";
```